# Regex to match word after keyword, including hypen after keyword

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex to produce the word after a keyword in a sentence. I have this regex that matches the word after "hello ".

```
(?<=hello )(\w+)
```

However, what I am having trouble with is that if, say, hello is hyphenated like hello-bye, then I want to save the hyphen and the word ("-bye"). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space then has to optional.  But then it can't be used in the negative lookbehind.

If it's fine as long the space isn't part of the capture group.

```
(?<=hello\b)[ ]*(-?\w+)
```

Comment: Ok, I don't know what programming language you use. So it could be that yours doesn't know the `\b`. It's a [wordboundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), to assure that 'hello' isn't directly followed by a word character.